# Мобильный вид веб-страниц

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, c#

Как определить, что на сайт вышли с мобильного устройства? (чтобы показывать страницу в мобильном виде)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашёл простое решение для любителей ASP.NET. В отличии от других ответов, этот с кодом :)

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){
    //прыгаем от радости - пришли с мобильного устройства
}
```

Comment: и сам-по-себе код простой

Answer (score 1):

Можно задействовать внешний API, например, [Яндекс.Детектор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/).

> API Яндекс.Детектор предоставляет возможность определения модели и характеристик мобильного устройства пользователя сайта по заголовкам HTTP-запросов, передаваемых браузером его устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Один из наиболее эффективных способов - это анализ заголовка [User Agent](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent). Однако основная проблема заключается в том, что возможные значения мобильных устройств постоянно меняются и пополняются.

Для решения этой проблемы часто используют:

1. Обновляемую базу мобильных устройств [WURFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WURFL).
2. Удаленные веб-сервисы, такие как [Яндекс.Детектор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/), [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=2) или [Tera-WURFL](http://www.tera-wurfl.com/wiki/index.php/Remote_Webservice)

Второй вариант проще в реализации, но может увеличить время отклика из-за необходимости делать дополнительный запрос к стороннему сервису.